# Botão submit não abre modal

Tags: php, javascript, modal

Bom dia, desculpem a pergunta..

Sou meio lento em Javascript, estou quebrando a cabeça com um codigo.
Queria exibir os dados do  dentro de uma janela modal quando da o submit, só que não abre a janela quando dou submit..

Se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço

Codigo abaixo ↓

```css
/* 
 SITE CRIADO E DESENVOLVIDO POR LEOW!
 QUALQUER PLAGIO DESSE SITE É CONSIDERADO UM CRIME!
*/

body {
  background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
 
}
#perguntas {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
}

#central {

 width: 800px;
 height: 1000px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0) transparent;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#centralizando {

 width: 800px;
 height: 600px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0) transparent;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#testt {
 
position: relative;
    right: -300px;
}

#logozinho {
position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: 30px;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: #0009;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- INICIO SITE -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Formulário whitelist - Primeiro comando RP</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<!-- FIM RODAPÉ -->

<!-- SCRIPT ETAPA 1 FORMULARIO OCULTA UMA DIV/MOSTRA OUTRA-->
<script>
function oculta(base, final){
ocultar=document.getElementById(base);
mostrar=document.getElementById(final);
ocultar.style.display="none";
mostrar.style.display="block";

}
</script>

<!-- SCRIPT ABRIR MODAL -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#enviar").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        var nome = $("#nome").val();
        $("#conteudo").empty();
        $("#conteudo").append("Nome: " + nome);
    });
</script>
<!-- FIM SCRIPTS -->
<body>
<!-- MENU BAR -->
<div class="topnav">
   <div id="testt">
  <a href="#home">Início</a>
  <a href="#news">Servidores</a>
  <a href="#contact">Donators</a>
  <a href="#about">Whitelist</a>
  <a href="#about">Equipe</a>
  <a href="#about">Regras</a>
  <a href="#" style=" left: 750px;  position: absolute;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Administração</a>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div id="logozinho">
 <img src="img/logo.png" style=" width: 180px;"></img>
 </div>
 <br>
 <!-- FIM MENU -->
 
 <!-- PRIMEIRA ETAPA -->
 <center><div id="centralizando" style="display:block">
    <div class="row">
    <br><br>
    <img src="img/logo.png" style=""></img>
      <h1><font color="#fFFFFF" style="font-family: fantasy;">PRIMEIRO COMANDO ROLEPLAY</font></h1>
   <label><font color="#fFFFFF" style="font-family: monospace;"> Seja bem vindo a whitelist do Primeiro Comando RP.</font><br></label>
   <label><font color="#fFFFFF" style="font-family: monospace;"> Pedimos para que você se conecte ao nosso discord clicando <a href="">aqui</a> e tambem leia as <a href="">regras aqui!</a><br>
   Para que você não fique perdido na hora de responder a whitelist. <br>
   Nosso servidor está cada vez melhorando mais para obtermos uma melhor experiencia no nosso roleplay!</font><br><br></label>
   
   <div class="botaoum" ><br>
                <input type="button" onclick="javascript:oculta('centralizando','central')" name="enviar1" value="Seguir para a Whitelist" class="btn btn-success">

            </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <!-- FIM PRIMEIRA ETAPA -->
 
<!-- SEGUNDA ETAPA FORMULARIO -->
<div id="central" style="display:none">
    <div class="row">
        <form action="link" method="POST" id="formulario">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <label>Qual é o seu nome?</label>
                <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome" class="form-control">
            </div>
  
  
            <div id="perguntas"><br>
                <label>Você leu as regras do servidor?</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="questao10" required="">
   <option name="resposta10" value="">Selecione uma opção</option>
   <option name="resposta10" value="A">Sim, eu realmente lí as regras do servidor!</option>
   <option name="resposta10" value="B">Não, eu não lí as regras do servidor!</option></select>
   </div>
   
   <div id="perguntas"><br>
                <label>Quem são os criadores do servidor?</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="questao1" required="">
   <option name="resposta1" value="">Selecione uma opção</option>
   <option name="resposta1" value="A">Leow e Escobar</option>
   <option name="resposta1" value="B">Whisky e Juca</option>
   <option name="resposta1" value="C">Juca e Leow</option>
   <option name="resposta1" value="B">Escobar e Whisky</option></select>
   </div>
   
            <div id="perguntas"><br>
                <label>O que é PowerGaming?</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="questao2" required="">
   <option name="resposta2" value="">Selecione uma opção</option>
   <option name="resposta2" value="A">Fazer algo no jogo, que pode ser feito na vida real</option>
   <option name="resposta2" value="B">Sair matando as pessoas na cidade</option>
   <option name="resposta2" value="C">Fazer algo no jogo, que não pode ser feito na vida real</option>
   <option name="resposta2" value="D">Atropelar as pessoas na cidade</option></select>
   </div>
   
   
            <div id="perguntas"><br>
                <label>O que é MetaGaming?</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="questao3" required="">
   <option name="resposta3" value="">Selecione uma opção</option>
   <option name="resposta3" value="A">É atropelar e fugir sem prestar ajuda</option>
   <option name="resposta3" value="B">É chamar um personagem pelo seu ID sem ter perguntado o nome</option>
   <option name="resposta3" value="C">É matar pessoas sem algum motivo ou razão</option>
   <option name="resposta3" value="D">É andar sobre montanhas com carros que não fariam isso na vida real</option></select>
   </div>
   
   <div id="perguntas"><br>
                <label>O que é safezone?</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="questao4" required="">
   <option name="resposta4" value="0">Selecione uma opção</option>
   <option name="resposta4" value="A">São lugares para regenerar a vida</option>
   <option name="resposta4" value="B">São lugares onde se vende armas</option>
   <option name="resposta4" value="C">São lugares onde se pode roubar e matar</option>
   <option name="resposta4" value="D">São lugares em que não se pode roubar ou matar</option></select>
   </div>
   
   <div id="perguntas"><br>
                <label>O que é VDM?</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="questao5" required="">
   <option name="resposta5" value="0">Selecione uma opção</option>
   <option name="resposta5" value="A">É matar outro jogador atropelado</option>
   <option name="resposta5" value="B">É cair da moto em movimento</option>
   <option name="resposta5" value="C">É matar em lugares proibidos</option>
   <option name="resposta5" value="D">É dar carona de carro para outro jogador</option></select>
   </div>
   
   <div id="perguntas"><br>
                <label>O que é RDM?</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="questao6" required="">
   <option name="resposta6" value="0">Selecione uma opção</option>
   <option name="resposta6" value="A">É matar um jogador porque ele tentou te matar</option>
   <option name="resposta6" value="B">É matar um jogador porque ele tentou te roubar</option>
   <option name="resposta6" value="C">É matar um jogador porque ele roubou seu carro</option>
   <option name="resposta6" value="D">É matar um jogador sem motivo</option></select>
   </div>
   
   
   <div id="perguntas"><br>
               <label>O que é anti RP?</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="questao7" required="">
   <option name="resposta7" value="0">Selecione uma opção</option>
   <option name="resposta7" value="A">É chamar um amigo seu pelo ID</option>
   <option name="resposta7" value="B">É desenvolver um papel igual da vida real</option>
   <option name="resposta7" value="C">É não desenvolver um papel da vida real</option>
   <option name="resposta7" value="D">É conversar com um jogador chamando pelo ID</option></select>
   </div>
   
   <div id="perguntas"><br>
               <label>Para assaltar as pessoas na cidade necessita ter no mínimo quantos policiais online?</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="questao8" required="">
   <option name="resposta8" value="0">Selecione uma opção</option>
   <option name="resposta8" value="A">1 Policial</option>
   <option name="resposta8" value="B">2 Policiais</option>
   <option name="resposta8" value="C">3 Policiais</option>
   <option name="resposta8" value="D">4 Policiais</option></select>
   </div>
   
   <div id="perguntas"><br>
               <label>Durante uma perseguição policial você perde o controle do veículo e capota, o que você faria em seguida?</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="questao9" required="">
   <option name="resposta9" value="0">Selecione uma opção</option>
   <option name="resposta9" value="A">Deslogaria para não perder minhas armas</option>
   <option name="resposta9" value="B">Tentaria desvirar o veículo para fugir mais rápido</option>
   <option name="resposta9" value="C">Sairia do veículo e tentaria fugir correndo</option>
   <option name="resposta9" value="D">Roubaria outro carro e tentaria fugir</option></select>
   </div>
   
   
            <div class="clearfix">&nbsp </div>
   
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" >
                <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-success">
            </div>
        </form>
 </div>
 </center>
  
 <!-- FIM FORMULARIO -->
 
<!-- RESULTADOS PHP DENTRO DA MODAL -->
<?php
 
$questao1 = $_POST["questao1"];
$questao2 = $_POST["questao2"];
$questao3 = $_POST["questao3"];
$questao4 = $_POST["questao4"];
$questao5 = $_POST["questao5"];
$questao6 = $_POST["questao6"];
$questao7 = $_POST["questao7"];
$questao8 = $_POST["questao8"];
$questao9 = $_POST["questao9"];
$questao10 = $_POST["questao10"];
 
echo "<b>Criadores 1</b> = ".$questao1."<br>";
echo "<b>Questao 2</b>= ".$questao2."<br>";
echo "<b>Questao 3</b> = ".$questao3."<br>";
echo "<b>Questao 4</b> = ".$questao4."<br>";
echo "<b>Questao 5</b> = ".$questao5."<br>";
echo "<b>Questao 6</b> = ".$questao6."<br>";
echo "<b>Questao 7</b> = ".$questao7."<br>";
echo "<b>Questao 8</b>= ".$questao8."<br>";
echo "<b>Questao 9</b>= ".$questao9."<br>";
echo "<b>Questao 10</b> = ".$questao10."<br><br><br>";
 
$resposta1 = "C";
$resposta2 = "C";
$resposta3 = "B";
$resposta4 = "D";
$resposta5 = "A";
$resposta6 = "D";
$resposta7 = "C";
$resposta8 = "B";
$resposta9 = "C";
$resposta10 = "A";
 
$acertou = 0;
$errou = 0;
 
if ($questao1 == $resposta1)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = 'blue'><i class='fas fa-times'></i> Obrigado por ler as regras!<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 1 errada<br></font>";
}
 
if ($questao2 == $resposta2)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = blue> Questao 2 correta<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 2 errada<br></font>";
}
 
if ($questao3 == $resposta3)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = blue> Questao 3 correta<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 3 errada<br></font>";
}
 
if ($questao4 == $resposta4)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = blue> Questao 4 correta<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 4 errada<br></font>";
}
 
if ($questao5 == $resposta5)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = blue> Questao 5 correta<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 5 errada<br></font>";
}
 
if ($questao6 == $resposta6)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = blue> Questao 6 correta<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 6 errada<br></font>";
}
 
if ($questao7 == $resposta7)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = blue> Questao 7 correta<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 7 errada<br></font>";
}
 
if ($questao8 == $resposta8)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = blue> Questao 8 correta<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 8 errada<br></font>";
}
 
if ($questao9 == $resposta9)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = blue> Questao 9 correta<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 9 errada<br></font>";
}
 
if ($questao10 == $resposta10)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = blue> Questao 10 correta<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 10 errada<br></font>";
}
 
$calc = 10;
$porcent = $calc * $acertou;
 
echo "<br><br> Voce <font color = blue>acertou</font> $acertou e <font color = red>errou</font> $errou.";
 
 
if ($acertou >=7)
{
echo "<br><br><b><blink>Muito bem, um total de $porcent % de acerto Clique <button href='http://google.com.br'>AQUI</button>para prosseguir!</blink></b>";
}
else
{
echo "<br><br><b><blink> Poxa você foi muito mal, teve um total de $porcent% de acerto, tente novamente!</blink></b>";
}
 
?>
<!-- RESULTADOS PHP DENTRO DA MODAL -->

        
    <!-- MODAL -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Resultados</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="conteudo">
                    <p>Resultados exibem aqui dentro</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <!-- FIM MODAL -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poderia elaborar um [mcve]? Parece que há muito código PHP aí que não deveria ter interferência com o fato do modal abrir ou não, o que acaba inserindo ruído na pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Amigo, Coloca este código Javascript depois da tag body. Mudei o evento, ao invés de escutar o evento de click do botao eu coloquei o evento de submit do formulário.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#formulario").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        var nome = $("#nome").val();
        $("#conteudo").empty();
        $("#conteudo").append("Nome: " + nome);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Todo `<button>` dentro de um `<form>` age como um submit, e isso recarrega a página, para evitar que a página seja recarregada você precisa PREVINIR o comportamento default do navegador com o comando `e.preventDefault();` sendo a primeira coisa a ser executada na sua função... caso contrário qq coisa feita depois não será vista porque o navegador irá tentar enviar seu formulário, recarregando a página...

As soluções aqui seriam ou usar um `e.preventDefault();` ou não usar um `<button>` e sim um `<a>`...